# Extensible ASP.NET Core 2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I need to create an ASP.NET Core 2 application that can be extensible.

An extension, is a project that reference the main assembly and can extends it adding new controllers, models (with EF migrations), views, razor pages, etc.

Because the extensions need use the main application base classes like base controller, base model or view/page layout, the main application cannot reference the module project (avoid circular references).

I'm not sure how can I achieve this, but the idea is an installation of the main project, can add new functionality simple putting the modules DLL (or by online market in the main application, that download the DLL).

In my research, I found [Applications parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.1), but my problem here is I need specify the part assembly in Startup class, and I need in installed the capacity of install modules without doing any changes in the code.

Some modules, need be extensible too, for example, an accounting module, need to connect with bank, and it have an interface that defines the methods of working with the bank, for example:

```
public interface IBankingOperation
{
    public async void PayInvoiceAsync(Invoice invoice);
    // More methods...
}
```

Then, differents projects can reference the banking assembly and provide implementation for differents banks.

In the main application, this modules can be installed like other modules, but checking the base module is intalled, for example, I can install the Santander module like other module, but only if banking module is installed (module dependency).

**In conclusion**, I need to create a modular ASP.NET Core 2 application, but the main assembly cannot reference the modules, the modules must reference the main assembly. The modules can contain Controllers, Models, Views, Pages, Etc.

Comment: I'll research about http://extcore.net/ tomorrow

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working the way you would like? I mean this kind of just works. ASP.NET Core will pull controllers from all referenced assemblies. Views can be embedded and referenced from other assemblies. It's not clear what you're actually looking for that you feel you don't already have.

Comment: @ChrisPratt My problem is I can't reference the others assembly in the main assembly because I need let a third-party teams create owns extensions, and I can't reference all third-party extensions in the main project. i need the main projects automatically load all assemblies in a directory if the assembly has some metadata that indicate is a extension of my application. The third-party extension need reference the main project because need extends some base classes of the main project like base controller, base model or layout of Razor Pages.

Answer (score 1):

In the main web app you would call a class which loads the extensions in the memory

`ModuleManager.LoadModules(Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, "Modules"));`

this is the load modules function

```
public static void LoadModules(string modulesFolder)
    {
        var appsFolders = new DirectoryInfo(modulesFolder).GetDirectories();

        foreach (var appFolder in appsFolders)
        {
            var binFolder = new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(appFolder.FullName, "bin"));
            if (!binFolder.Exists)
            {
                continue;
            }
            var assemblies = AssemblyProvider.GetAssemblies(binFolder.FullName);
            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                var iModuleClass = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type => type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IModule))
                                    && type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null);
                if (iModuleClass != null)
                {
                    var module = Activator.CreateInstance(iModuleClass) as IModule;
                    module.ModuleFolder = appFolder;
                    Modules.Add(module); 
                    Assemblies.Add(assembly);
                    break;
                }
            }



        }

    }
```

then you should have an interface which should be implemented by each module the class which implement this interface should do the work of registering services and database models and all staff needed and you will load them as follows

```
public static IEnumerable<IExtensionRegister> GetModuleRegistrars()
    {
        lock (Modules)
        {
            return Modules.Select(item => item.Registrar).Where(item=>item!=null).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Finally, I used a ExtCore Nuget Package, that have a class that loads assemblies in directory, and allow you to implement a custom AssemblyProvider to filter that assemblies are loaded.

Comment: Yes it is good but have some problems one of them is the resources such as views, assets and static files must be embedded with the assembly

Comment: Can you explain it or link an article talking about it? Thanks

Comment: The best thing you can do is to check how orchardcore and aspnetboilerplate do the molecularity, they are both open source
https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it, but I didn't find the problem with views and resources. For me it is working correctly.